# SortofSorting Kattis

Tags: python

Hi please I need ur help in a problem :
this is my code :

```
n=int(input())
W=[]
while(n!=0):
    for i in range(n):
        W.append(input())
    for i in range(0,len(W)-1) :
        for j in range(i+1,len(W)):
            if W[i][0:2] > W[j][0:2]:
                Aide=W[i]
                W[i]=W[j]
                W[j]=Aide
    n=int(input())
    
    for word in W:
        print(word)
        
    print('\n')
    W=[]
```

it works for two inputs in and wrong answer after .. I don't know what's missing!!!
(problem : Write a program that sorts a list of student last names, but the sort only uses the first two letters of the name. Nothing else in the name is used for sorting. However, if two names have the same first two letters, they should stay in the same order as in the input (this is known as a ‘stable sort’). Sorting is case sensitive based on ASCII order (with uppercase letters sorting before lowercase letters, i.e.,.)

Comment: as much as the problem statement is clear, it would be better if you post a sample input and output, in your case the list of names

Comment: @python_learner I did this code in kattis compiler and it works just for the first input , after it gives me wrong answer.. I don't know what's the input that gives an error ..

Comment: you can paste any sample input and output, so anyone who views the question can know what to work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I tried to fix your code, what I did was to change your sort to a Lambda function where it uses the .sort() function and sort using the two first letters (because sorting strings in python is sorting using the ASCII value of every character so it respects that A<B<...<Z<a<...<z)
and this is the code

```
while (True):
    n = int(input())
    W = []
    if (n == 0):
        break
    for i in range(n):
        W.append(input())
    W.sort(key=lambda x:(x[0:2]))
    for word in W:
        print(word)
    print()
```

I think you wanted to use BubbleSort right, I suppose your implementation is wrong that's why. this is BubbleSort in this problem

```
for i in range(len(W) - 1):
        for j in range(len(W)-i-1):
            if W[j][0:2]> W[j+1][0:2]:
                W[j],W[j+1]=W[j+1],W[j]
```

Comment: I am guessing OP wants to manually write a sort algorithm as opposed to using the key parameter

Comment: @python_learner i think they're talking about this problem https://open.kattis.com/problems/sortofsorting

Comment: thank you for lambda function it works .. but I also compared the only two fisrt letters ` if W[i][0:2] > W[j][0:2]:
`but i didn't work .. i don't know what's wrong